# JQuery DateTimePicker format

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Jquery DateTimePicker
Currently I have this function.

```
 $(".datetime").click(function(event){
        $(this).datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-d'});
        allowTimes:[
                    '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', '17:00',
                    '17:05', '17:20', '19:00', '20:00'
                   ]
         });
```

displays : 2015/05/29 11:54

I want the display to be in this format : 2015-05-18 19:00.
I tried adding timeformat:'hh:mm'. But it Didnt work. Any idea why the dateformat changes when I change time format ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the website http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

It should be like this

```js
jQuery('...').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
});
```

Notice that the parameter is not `dateFormat` but `format`.

Comment: 5 secs late, i was just for posting same exact answer.

Comment: when i use that format it displays as :  2015-05-29 11:49:00.0. I dont want seconds and nanoseconds

Comment: Yes, it is just an example. Change the content of the example for your format and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I notice in the code: when I enter the date, its taking as 2015-05-28 12:19. After saving and retrieving it from the backend it displays as 2015-06-06 12:18:00.0. If its something to do with backend I will look into, before that I wanted to ask is it in the front end ?